# UWP: webview does not display page using navigateToString method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview, uwp

I am trying to use [webview element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) in a universal app using javascript. My aim is to browse some websites adding some content of my own to its html document.

First, I set src attribute of webview to www.example.com and it browses the site. This was just to make sure the webview is capable of browsing the site.

Next, I tried getting the html and load it to webview using navigateToString method like this:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
        webView.navigateToString(data);
    });
```

This causes the page to be loaded out of shape (aperarently some .js or .css files are not loaded or blocked from running), or it isn't even loaded.

I wonder what is the difference loading the page by its url and loading its html by manually like this. And is there a workaround I can overcome this problem.

Note: I'm new at both js and html.

Comment: Does the css and js files referenced in the hml you downloaded use a relative path or absolute?  I would not expect the relative path to work if you are showing the html string in the webview control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web page is usually not made of a single HTML file. In order to make it work, you will have to retrieve not only the HTML but also the javascript and the css files. 
This can be a tedious work.

If you are trying to open something from the web, the easiest way is to perform a regular [navigate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301842.aspx) which will take the URI as parameter and perform a "full" browse (as the browser will do). The retrieval/loading of the CSS/JS will be done for you.

If you want to open a local page (local to your application), [navigateToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301844.aspx) is a good path but you will have to host locally all the page dependencies (css/js fiels) or embed all the style and code in the HTML page itself.

Comment: But if I use navigate() method, I won't be able to alter the browsed document, will I?

Comment: You will not be able to modify the page code directly but since it is a webview, you can still use invokeScriptAsync() to execute some javascript that will alter the page

Comment: Yes, but invokeScriptAsync() function requires the invoked script function to be defined in the html document. Because I can't change html document, I don't have my script functions in it to call. Do you know a way that I can attach my script to a html file that wasn't created by me?

Comment: The script function does not need to be defined in the HTML. You can use eval() to inject your own code to the HTML page. Something like webview.invokeScriptAsync("eval(""function() { /* do something */ }();""); The eval() function in JS transforms the string you provide to executable code and run it.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for making things clear. That answers my question.

Comment: @Vincent How can I host the page dependencies locally?

Comment: "you will have to host locally all the page dependencies (css/js fiels) or embed all the style and code in the HTML page itself." Can you elaborate on this part please? Navigate() is not an option for me since Edge doesn't 'load' res protocol.